# How can I handle returning an error from a getter method?

Tags: c++, exception, return, getter

I am wondering how can I return an error from a getter method in this situation?

```
class A 
{
private:
  int a;
  int b;
public:
  const int& get(int i) 
  {
    if (i == 1) return a;
    else if (i == 2) return b;
    // else... what to do here? I get a warning if I don't put anything.
  }
};
```

Comment: [Throwing exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) may be.

Comment: `throw std::invalid_argument("i should equal 1 or 2");` maybe

Comment: does throwing exceptions give a big overhead if the method is used often?

Comment: You could `throw`.  You could `assert`.  You could change the return to an `std::optional`.  You could change the signature to `bool try_get(int i, int*& out_value)` and return `false` if unable to set the out_value pointer to `a` or `b`.  You could make two getters, `int& get_a() { return a; }` and `int& get_b() { return b; }`.  Is this a bad situation that arises often, or a "never happen" situation only may happen if someone made an oops?

Comment: It may happen if someone chooses the wrong number for i, it should not happen unless it slips. Like in a typo.

Comment: Nitpicking: To return an `int` as `const int&` appears a bit over-engineered to me. Assuming that the `const int&` will be compiled as a kind of pointer internally, this might result in an unnecessary indirection (to access the contents of the const reference) as well as even more bytes to return (e.g. on a 64 bit arch. where `int` usually still has 32 bit). Furthermore, assuming you cannot or don't want to `throw` in error case: With `int` just `return` an integral. With `const int&`, you need something addressable, e.g. a `static int dummy;`.

Comment: If you have c++17 you could change `const int& get(int i)` to `std::optional<int> get(int i)` like in this example: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdoptional-how-when-and-why/#optional-is-mandatory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdoptional-how-when-and-why/#optional-is-mandatory)

Comment: @lucmobz On a modern compiler throwing an exception only costs if the exception is actually thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**: You don't need to return a `const int&` to your member class, `int` is enough.

The C++ way for this is Exceptions, but i don't like them and i want suggest some other way based on some situations:

1. The Getter function must do some operations and then return the result; In this case we could return a `std::pair<boo, Type_Of_Result>` which is boolean type indicate "It's a successful operation ?":

```cpp
class A {
 private:
  int  m_value;

 public:
  A(const int value):
    m_value(value) {
  }

  template<typename T>
  using return_t = std::pair<bool, T>;

  return_t<int>  get() const {
    return { true, m_value };
  }
};
```

2. Okay we got the return value status, But if it fails, how to find why?: In this case we could create a `Result` class which take care of Error message and return value:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Result {
  T return_value;
  bool its_okay;
  std::string message;
};

class A {
  // ...

  Result<int>  get() const {
    return { m_value, true, "All right" };
  }
};
```